# LightSail instances - Changed the file permission to 644 but still the caching plugin shows the error

Tags: wordpress, caching, litespeed

I have changed the file permissions of wp-config.php to 644. But still getting the same error---> wp-config.php operation failed when changing `WP_CACHE` const: File /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-config.php is not writable.

Can anyone help in this?

Changed the file permissions to 644 as per some pervious questions found on this platform, but it's not working in my case.